# Styling <p> tag inside <div> by using CSS

Tags: html, css, styling

(HtMl)

```
<div>
  <h2>I am another awesome h2</h2>

  <p>number one paragraph</p>

  <p>I'm the second paragraph inside this div!</p>
</div>

<p>PARAGRAPH NOT INSIDE A DIV</p>


<div>
  <h2>A less awesome h2</h2>

  <p>number one</p>

  <p>One last paragraph here!</p>
</div>
```

(CSS)

I tried to use nth-of-type and nth-child but I cannot choose the two P element inside SECOND DIV.

Can anyone help?

Note: I have too many P tag and DIV inside my webpage. I want to choose those without using class or id.

Comment: Please scale your demo down to a minimal representation of the problem and also include relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and demo links only used to support what is actually in the question.

Comment: `div p {.../*styles for p-tags inside a div*/...}` will choose both `p` inside a `div` in your case. Or you need to reach the 2nd `p` only?

Comment: i want to choose both P inside the SECOND DIV only . without using CLASS or ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using selector is pretty simple in this case, just try

```
div:nth-of-type(2) p {...}
```

Comment: i am sorry for misunderstanding , i knew how to style all P element inside DIV`s in my webpage . my question about how to style the two P element inside the second DIV in my HTML code not all P tags in my webpage , and please without using ID or CLASS.

Comment: use the following css `div:nth-of-type(2) p{...}`, should work

Comment: today you really make me happy , i was looking for this solution before 3 days . you add to me very useful info today .